# Why it is returning me Class extends value #<Object> is not a constructor or null in React console?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Thanks for reading my post I get this error on my code : "Class extends value # is not a constructor or null". Here is my code:

```
class App extends React{
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  array:[
    {
      name:'a',
      age:34
    },
    {
      name:'b',
      age:67
    },
    {
      name:'c',
      age:99
    },
    {
      name:'c',
      age:32
    },
    {
      name:'d',
      age:32
    }
  ]  
  }
}

render() {
return (
  <div>
    <p></p>
    {this.state.array.map((rt)=>{
      {rt.name}
      {rt.age}
    })}
  </div>
  )
  }
 }
 export default App;
```

Thank you for any help given,

Have a good day

Comment: Voting to close as unreproducible/typo, you should extend `React.Component`, not `React`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend `React.Component` and not `React`. `React` is the whole default export and not a constructor itself.